# Getting ClassNotFound Exception for class MkActivityMethod

Tags: java, svn

I am trying to use `JackRabbit lbrary` for SVN chekin operation.
What I run my code through individual program this works fine. But when I run using web based project it doesn't work.

Code compiles fine but gives me runtime exception at following line :

```
MkActivityMethod activityMethod = new MkActivityMethod(url);
```

The exception is :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jackrabbit/webdav/client/methods/MkActivityMethod
```

My project has `jackrabbit-standalone-2.6.4.jar` included in my eclipse jars as well as in project `web-Inf/lib` folder

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution  :

- Try to build the project once again
- Check the JDK version for the builder and Server JRE
- Try clean the project (In eclipse , Project menu -> Clean )

**Reason :**

After you compile your code, you end up with `.class` files for each class in your program. These binary files are the bytecode that Java interprets to execute your program. The `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that the classloader, which is responsible for dynamically loading classes, cannot find the `.class` file for the class that you're trying to use. It probably indicates that you haven't set the classpath option when executing your code. [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) explains how to set the classpath when you execute.

Comment: I rebuild the project but same is happening :(
JDK version for eclipse : 1.6
Server JDK 1.6

Comment: Hi Sijith PS. Thaks for your reply.
I cleaned the project, restarted the server but still facing the same issue :( 
Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Hi Sujith PS thanks again for your help. If I remove jar file from eclipse my project gives errors at compile time because my code uses that class in jar. Is there anythign more you can suggest?

Comment: Did you check the Build path of your project ? Did you find any error ?

Comment: if I add the jar then there are no errors. If I remove the jar then there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously something wrong with your classpath. What Web Server Are You Using?

Comment: I am using Tomcat 6.
Tomcat JRE is jdk 1.6.
Also eclipse JRE point to 1.6

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the class path as I have added respective jar in my web-Inf/lib.

Comment: @user2745675 Try putting jackrabbit-standalone-2.6.4.jar in $CATALINA_HOME/lib folder to be sure this is a classpath problem ;) Refer to this article for more info: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: I tried putting the jar in catalina home/lib bu after that I am not able to get login screen as well. So that is something which is not correct I suppose. BTW thanks for your reply Michali

Comment: OK, one more thing then - is your lib folder in war inside web-Inf or WEB-INF?

Comment: Hi Michali, thanks for your reply. My Lib folder is inside WEB-INF